# Solr Indexing Splitting Field On Delimiter

Tags: xml, solr

I am trying to setup a Solr index with some data, however I would like to send one of my fields down as pipe delimited and have it split on the Solr end e.g.

```
<doc>
 <add>
  <field name="cat">a|b|c<field>
 </add>
</doc>
```

For a multi-valued field declared as

```
<field name="cat" type="str_split_on_pipe" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" />
```

And the split on pipe type is

```
<fieldType name="str_split_on_pipe" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
  <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\|\s*" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <!--<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>-->
      <!-- this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes
     possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with stemming. -->
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\|\s*" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <!--<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>-->
      <!-- this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes
     possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with stemming. -->
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I would expect this to be the same as if I send the document with three different `cat` fields, however it doesn't seem to do much and just keeps returning my pipe separated list.

Is what I am trying to do possible, and if so where have I gone wrong?

Thanks,
Amar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a `PatternTokenizer` will change only the internal representation and not the stored value. If you want Solr to treat it as a multi-valued field with multiple displayable values, then you need to send in 3 different `cat` fields.

If you are using `DataImportHandler`, then you can use the `RegexTransformer` to split the data.

Comment: Thanks, `DataImportHandler` is just what I was after!

Comment: Remember that  RegexTransformer is a regex so if you need to split by pipes for example, you have to escape them (splitBy="\|" )