# Solr copyField mixed with RegexTransformer

Tags: solr, field, multivalue

**Scenario:**

In the database I have a field called *Categories* which of type string and contains a number of digits pipe delimited such as `1|8|90|130|`

**What I want:**

In Solr index, I want to have 2 fields:

- Field *Categories*_ *pipe* which would contain the exact string as in the DB i.e. `1|8|90|130|`
- Field *Categories* which would be a multi-valued field of type INT containing values 1, 8, 90 and 130

For the latter, in the entity specification I can use a regexTransformer then I specify the following field in data-config.xml:
`<field column="Categories" name="Navigation" splitBy="\|"/>` and then specify the field as multi-valued in schema.xml

What I do not know is how can I 'copy' the same field twice and perform regex splitting only on one. I know there is the `copyField` facility that can be defined in schema.xml however I can't find a way to transform the copied field because from what I know (and I maybe wrong here), transformers are only available in the entity specification.

As a workaround I can also send the same field twice from the entity query but in reality, the field *Categories* is a computed field (selects nested) which is somewhat expensive so I would like to avoid it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting it at `data-config.xml`. You could do that in your `schema.xml`. Here is what you could do,

1. Create a **fieldType** with tokenizer `PatternTokenizerFactory` that uses regex to split based on `|`.
2. **FieldSplit**: Create a `multivalued` field using this `new fieldType`, will eventually have 1,8,90,130
3. **FieldOriginal**: Create String field (if you need no analysis on that), that preserves original value 1|8|90|130|
4. Now you can use copyField to copy FieldSplit , FieldOriginal values based on your need.

Check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502421/solr-indexing-splitting-field-on-delimiter), it is similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I have a problem with point 3. Although it is a multivalued field, the 'stored' value is still just one value of `1|8|90|130`. The tokenizer does nothing to the stored value, it changes the internal structure of the index for that value. In fact that's what the question you referenced says as well.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the PatternTokenizerFactory applies to the *stored valued* from a copyfield, at least that's the problem I seem to be having.  The regex effect shows up in the facets, but not in the stored value for FieldSplit.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two columns from the same data and treat them separately.

SELECT categories, categories as categories_pipe FROM category_table

Then you can split the "categories" column, but index the other one as-is.